# SIOCGIWFREQ ioctl returning error 22 EINVAL - Invalid argument, why?

Tags: c++, linux, wifi, ioctl

I am struggling to read current frequency channel of Wifi card using [Wireless Extension Tools for Linux library](http://www.labs.hpe.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) with following `Qt/C++` method:

```
const UeTypeCurrentFrequencyChannel& UeNetworkManager::ueCurrentFrequencyChannel(const QString& interfaceName)
{
    static UeTypeCurrentFrequencyChannel result=UeTypeCurrentFrequencyChannel();
    iwreq wrq;
    iw_range range;
    int kernelSocket=iw_sockets_open();

    if(iw_get_range_info(kernelSocket,
                         interfaceName.toLocal8Bit().constData(),
                         &range)>=0)
    {
        if(iw_get_ext(kernelSocket,
                      interfaceName.toLocal8Bit().constData(),
                      SIOCGIWFREQ,
                      &wrq)>=0)
        {
            //BUG current frequency and channel is not read, it might be becuase of nonroot credentials - it returns error 22 (EINVAL - Invalid argument), why?
            result.first=iw_freq2float(&(wrq.u.freq));
            result.second=iw_freq_to_channel(result.first.toDouble(),
                                             &range);

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << "success - current channel:"
                     << result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.first=QString(interfaceName);
            result.second=QString(tr("current channel read failed."));

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << "error (iw_get_ext):"
                     << errno;
        }   // if
    }
    else
    {
        result.first=QString(interfaceName);
        result.second=QString(tr("current channel read failed."));

        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                 << "error (iw_get_range_info):"
                 << errno;
    }   // if

    iw_sockets_close(kernelSocket);

    return result;
}   // ueCurrentFrequencyChannel
```

Now, `iw_get_ext` always returns `-1` and `errno` is set to value of `22`. I've taken a look at the [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) and search for error `22` and I've got following error declaration:
`#define EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */`.
Why am I getting `Invalid argument` error while trying to query current frequency channel of network adapter with `ioctl`? I've **launched application** containing this code as **normal user and as root**, same result any time:

```
static const UeTypeCurrentFrequencyChannel& UeNetworkManager::ueCurrentFrequencyChannel(const QString&) error(iw_get_ext): 22
```

Why, what am I missing?

**Addendum #1:**
If I scan WiFi cards and networks using `iwlist` **from terminal**, I get all needed info, regardless if I run it as **normal user** or **root**.

**Addendum #2:**
The code has been upgraded, `iw_get_range_info()` works.

**Addendum #3:**
The situation have just got weired; On random occasions, I get succes:

```
static const UeTypeCurrentFrequencyChannel& UeNetworkManager::ueCurrentFrequencyChannel(const QString&) success - current channel: QPair(QVariant(double, 2.412e+09),QVariant(int, 1))
```

which same as `iwlist scan output`:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 64:6E:EA:22:21:D4
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

After some time of programming/testing app, bug reappears, however `iwlist scan` still works. I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` with kernel `Linux workstation 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.
Is it maybe possible the problem has to something to do with `WiFi` card `Power Management`?

Comment: Which connection mode do you use when testing this code?

Comment: I am not connected to any WiFi network, I just want to gather available WiFi networks attributes into single data structure (SSID, available channels/frequencies, current channel/frequency, access point strength, security mode) - basicly *cell info* of `iwlist scan`.

Comment: You have problem with exec your function after scanning, don`t you? Can you get little more info about what you do?

Comment: Look at [cfg80211_wext_giwfreq](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/wext-compat.c#L783). That is why you get EINVAL of current channel if your Wi-Fi  is not used any connection mode.

Comment: @Dmitry which function do you have in mind?

Comment: I mean  ueCurrentFrequencyChannel. You have problem with this function, do not you?

Comment: @Dmitry the whole code of `ueCurrentFrequencyChannel` is listed. And your previous comment regarding `cfg80211_wext_giwfreq`, good guideline, however if WiFi is not used by any connection mode, why then `iwlist scan` command works and lists wifi networks?

Comment: The command **iwlist scan** works because Wi-Fi card switches to AP client mode on the scan time.

Comment: @Dmitry I am looking at `iwlist.c` and I cannot find the code which switched Wi-Fi card to `AP Client Mode`.

Comment: Because iwlist is front end to different wireless device drivers that support WEXT(Linux Wireless Extensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [cfg80211_wext_giwfreq](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/wext-compat.c#L783). That is why you get `EINVAL` of current channel if your **`Wi-Fi` card is not used any connection mode**.
The command `iwlist` scan works because Wi-Fi card **switches to `AP client mode`** on the scan time.